# Epson won’t print black with all new cartridges; won’t acknowledge replacement

Tags: printing, printer, ink

I have an Epson XP-400 series printer.  All of the cartridges have been replaced, to the tune of 41 dollars.
The black ink will not print at all.  The cartridge was half full when I replaced it.  The yellow and cyan cartridges said they need replacing so I replaced them.  Then as soon as I did it said the magenta one needed replacing though it was half full.  I replaced it anyway.

I have turned off the printer numerous times.   I have uninstalled and reinstalled the software.

The printer still says the cyan and yellow need to be replaced and still does not print black.

I would throw it away except I now have 41 dollars invested in ink, which is half the cost of a new printer.

Comment: Don't know Epson printer cartridges - but if there are contacts on the cartridge, you should look at the corresponding contacts in the printer. They might need cleaning. Use isopropyl alcohol and cotton swabs.

Comment: Probably a bad printhead.

Comment: did you run a printhead cleaning cycle?

Comment: 1. Are the cartridges original equipment manufacturer (OEM) or from another vendor? It might be the cartridges, in which case go back to the vendor. 2. Some cartridges need to be reset after ink has been added; if these are refilled, the reset might have been foroitten.

Comment: I have had 6 epson printers, and i can tell you that there are times when nothing you do short of knowing the service codes will get the thing to work again, I have even aquired a set of  free carts direct from epson (tech call) to solution it, and that did not fix it. It is possible that correctally connected , correctally installed , real actual OEM carts do not properly unlock the system, if it has gone wackey, it occurs in the hardware of the printer itself.   I lost 2 that way that were not worth saving.